# Can we create CMS Workspace via API?

Tags: rest-api, salesforce-cms

guys. Just wondering If there's chance to CREATE CMS Workspace and add content there via API? I know there was Summer '22 release that added CMS "Managed Content Resources" but they allow to GET attributes of CMS Workspace but not to create. Thanks in advance for answers!

Comment: I don't think this is currently supported. There is no supporting documentation to confirm that creation of CMS Workspace via API is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed with the concerned Salesforce team that there is no public API exposed for creating a CMS Workspace.

As you are already aware only [retrieving a CMS Workspace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_cms_space.htm) is supported(Beta feature).

Comment: Please advise if we have a CLI/API (Non UI) way to export and import Salesforce workspaces - folders structure and files between two Salesforce sandboxes?